# How to get two values, directly proportional, based on one variable change.

Tags: calculus

I am having a hard time solving this this equation so I decided it's time to call for help from the experts.

Considering the following values:

- $x_{\textrm{max}} = 160$;
- $y_{\textrm{max}} = 420$;
- top = variable number;
- left = $0$;

Top will start with a value higher than $y_{\textrm{max}}$. This value will decrease sequentially until it is the same $y_{\textrm{max}}$.

At the same time the top decreases, left needs to increase until equals $x_{\textrm{max}}$. So left needs to be equal to $x_{\textrm{max}}$ at the same time top is equal to $y_{\textrm{max}}$.

Let's say the difference between top and $y_{\textrm{max}}$ (top-$y_{\textrm{max}}$) is $120$, by the time top $= 120$, left variable needs to be equal to $x_{\textrm{max}}$.

Also if the difference between top and $y_{\textrm{max}}$ (top-$y_{\textrm{max}}$) is $437$, by the time top $= 120$, left needs to be equal to $x_{\textrm{max}}$.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
r = \frac{   x_\max  - \text{left}}{\text{top} - y_\max} .
$$

That is the relative rate at which the values change. For each decrease of $1$ unit in $y$ you must increase $x$ by $r$ units.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Hi Ethan,

Not sure I am solving the formula correctly.
Considering left is the measure that needs to increase when y moves and the following values for this example:

xMax = 160, yMax = 420, top = 520 and left = 0;

It's returning r with a value of 1.6. If I increase the value of top to 610 it returns r with the value of 0.8421052631578947
it's not making sense to me how left should increase 1.6 parts of xMax when top is it's 520.

Comment: @MarioAndrade You misread what increases. In the numerical example you give, each time you decrease $y$ by $1$ you increase the value of $x$ by $1.6$, not by "$1.6$ parts of xMax". Then the $100$ that $y$ is above yMax turns into the $160$ that $x$ is below xMax. When you increase $y$ in your second scenario the $0.84$ is about right, since the $y$ gap is now larger than the $x$ gap. (Please don't use all those extraneous digits after the decimal point.)